# Calculating f(7,8,9) with linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

f : R^3 → R^2 is linear. We know that f(1,0,0) = (6,5), f(0,1,0) = (4,3) and f(0,0,1) = (2,1). Calculate f(7,8,9).

Comment: Have you tried  anything?

Comment: This sounds tough.

Comment: My problem is what to do with the (6,5) , (4,3) and (2,1)

Comment: This problem is very easy since you know the images of the standard unit vectors. You can multiply the 7,8,9 with the images. The problem would have been much nicer if the mapped vectors are NOT unit vectors...

Comment: Linear function means $f(a+b) = f(a)+f(b)$

Answer (score 0):

It's just $$7(6,5)+8(4,3)+9(2,1)$$

Answer (score 0):

We know that

$$(7,8,9) = 7(1,0,0) + 8(0,1,0) + 9(0,0,1)$$
and so

$$f(7,8,9) =  f(7(1,0,0) + 8(0,1,0) + 9(0,0,1))$$
and because $f$ is linear

\begin{align}
&=7 \cdot f(1,0,0)  + 8 \cdot f(0,1,0) + 9 \cdot (0,0,1) \\ \\ &= 7(6,5) +8(4,3)+9(2,1)
\\ \\ &=(42,35) + (32,24)+(18,9)
\\ \\ &=(92,68)
\end{align}